# Ugh! JSoup meltdown

Tags: android, dom, jsoup

I'd like to preface my question with an apology - which will make this into a 2 part question....double apology. 
I am struggling with JSoup (again) 1st apology for repeatedly asking and not learning well enough yet - so can anyone suggest some reading beyond the usual searches for something that will help me  understand how to decipher the DOM each time I try this?

If you are still inclined to help, this time, within the doc returned I have:

```
    <a href="/logitech-logitech-wireless-keyboard-k270-with-long-range-wireless-920-003051/info"><span id="priceProductQA1" class="productPrice">&#36;29.99</span></a>
```

and I want to grab the href and price "29.99".
I've tried

```
   doc = Jsoup.connect(srchStr).get();
    for (Element choices : doc.select("a:has(.productPrice)")){
      absHref = choices.attr("abs:href"); 
      String pricetxt = choices.text();
```

and about 10 other ways to no avail. Any better ideas for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
for( Element element : doc.select("span.productPrice") ) // Select all 'span' tags with a 'productPrice' class and iterate over them
{
    final String price = element.text(); // save the price (= text of element)
    final String link = element.parent().absUrl("href"); // Get the 'a' tag (= parent of 'span' tag) and its absolute (!) URL

    // ... 
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. Select the `span` tag because you can easy decide if its the one you need (has a class, while `a` has none)
2. Iterate over each element from 1.
3. Get the price of the element
4. Select the parent of the `span` tag since it contains the required url
5. Select the *absolute* URL; if you want the relative one, use `attr("href")` instead

Btw. if you are 100% shure there's only one of such elements on this website you can replace the *for*-Loop by `Element element = doc.select("span.productPrice").first();`, followed by the other two lines of code.

Comment: Nope - not cutting it. I threw in:

Comment: tv2.append("\r\n" + price + "X" + "\r\n"); after assigning to the strings, but this doesn't even execute. It will set or append tv2 up to this point, but not after. No crash nor exception either...?

Comment: I added the line to apend a textview in order to debug and see the results - as in my comment above. It should append the value of the price variable, plus an "X" character. Since it does not even append the X character, I assume it's not executing the 2 lines above it, which are:  final String price = element.text(); and  final String link = element.parent().absUrl("href");

Comment: If you write only a `X`, is it shown then? You should also check if a.) the document is parsed, b.) the selector has some elements (= `doc.select(...)` doesn't return an empty array and c.) the textview is updated correctly.

Comment: It's been getting stuck at the parse process and seemingly running in a loop. With the debugger, I can see that it is in fact grabing the doc, but it is vastly different than what the browser's View Source was showing me. Hmmm....no spans....

Comment: Does the website use javascript for its content or is there an error-page in your document? Maybe the website redirects you to another one or required eg. useragent.

Comment: It might redirect to a mobile page...which the PC browser would miss, but the emulator would be directed into.

Comment: I will mark the answer as the correct answer - The original question did not disclose the underlying issue. The answer did provide a correct response to the question as posted.

Comment: I had a similar situation; possible you can find the redirect part or how a potential mobile-link is generated.